# How to change Transform Orientation with keyboard in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, shortcut

How I can change `Transform Orientation` with the keyboard in Ubuntu? In some linux systems (and many others) <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> are a system combination to show application menu and are captured by the OS.

Comment: So is Ctrl Alt Numpad 0 for *Align Active Camera to View*, which is super handy... I usually disable a bunch of the GNOME keyboard shortcuts. (For example, to minimize, I use [Alt Spacebar] + [N] instead of Ctrl Alt Numpad 0.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Personally I'd change the desktop manager binding from alt to super, but in Blender you can change it by going into **User Preferences > Input**. Then type in the search box "**Orientation**". You can click on the "**Alt Spacebar**" field, after which you can give the wanted key combination for Orientation Selection.